# Unable to properly add TR to HTML from JS script

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I keep getting an indexing error while trying to add TR tags to my HTML using the innerHTML attribute. This is what the JS script looks like.

```
var myTbody = document.querySelector(".table");

var button = document.querySelector(".add-stock");
var input = document.querySelector(".stock-input");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var td = document.querySelectorAll("td");

  var row = myTbody.insertRow(td.length + 1);
  var cell_univeral = row.insertCell(td.length - 1);
  cell_univeral.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

And this is the related html document:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Technical</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
      integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/technical.css')}}"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Technical</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Alpha-Beta</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Partition</a>
            <a class="nav-link disabled">More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="top-form">
          <form action='#' method="post">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label"
                >Ticker Symbols</label
              >
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control stock-input"
                id="exampleInputEmail1"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                name="nm"
              />

              <div id="symbol" class="form-text">Add stocks one at a time</div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
              <div class="add-button">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-stock">Add</button>
              </div>
              <div class="submit-button">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">
              Submit
            </button>
                      <div class="spinner-border my-spinner hidden" role="status">
  <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</div>
</div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-from">
          <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <th>Symbol <span class="counter"></span></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="table-body">
             
        
             
            </tbody>
          </table>

        
          <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            It may take longer for multiple stocks
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='script/technical.js')}}"
    /></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that for the first two click events i have no problems whatsoever though i get this error when i click again

```
Uncaught DOMException: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
```

It seems like I'm trying to change the innerHTML of an item that is out of range but i honestly don't know what the actual problem is and how to fix it. Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you share all the HTML code, I think some parts are missing to solve it, execute on Codespinet and we can see the error, too.

Comment: Your `tbody` element has a class of `table-body`, not `table`. Also, it should be `class`, not `calss`

Comment: I will now update the HTML code with the whole thing